# OSX: Monitoring launchd, daemons and agents

Tags: objective-c, macos, launchd

Is there a way we can monitor launchD itself i.e. if a job is getting loaded or unloaded from launchd daemon/agent list? For instance can any administrative app register to receive an event whenever a new plist is loaded or unloaded by the launchD daemon such as by firing this command: `launchctl load/unload /Library/LaunchDaemons(or launchAgents)/test.plist`?

Polling is one option but is there any resource efficient way?

Any help would be appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is exactly what you're looking for but there's an extremely powerful tool on OSX called `dtrace`. You can use it to see all sorts of things happening on the system and filter them as you wish e.g syscalls.

With your specific scenario I would even take a look at `dtruss` which is a much easier to use tool that uses dtrace to give you information: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dtruss.1m.html
It should be rather simple to get a 'prompt' from dtruss every time a `launchctl` call is made, I'm not sure what information you want to get out of the call though.

`dtrace` has whole books written on how to use it and write signatures for it. If you can't get everything you need from `dtruss` you can look into it a little more.

Also not these are both command line tools, if you're looking for something programatic you'll have a little more work ahead of you.

Comment: the thing that i am looking for is to capture the event when an admin user tries to unload my daemon say by firing this command from command line: sudo unload xyz.plist..is there a way to capture this event from dtruss?

Comment: I'd like to say yes. If you use it to see all the system calls made by `launchctl` and then call unload yourself you can see which system call you can filter to. A big advantage of `dtrace` in this case might be that it's easier to see when your `plist` file gets opened by any process.